# What's the term for expressions like "man's man" or "lawyer's lawyer"?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

To indicate an exemplar or someone well-respected within their own group or occupation, sometimes you see expressions like "man's man" or "lawyer's lawyer." Is there a name for this construction?

This isn't to be confused with someone who provides a service serving another in the same profession, like a lawyer defending another who's been sued.

Some examples of the expression:

[Dennis Drabelle in the *Washington Post*:](http://www.washingtonpost.com/entertainment/books/the-lawyers-lawyer-by-james-sheehan/2013/01/18/678fd894-58eb-11e2-9fa9-5fbdc9530eb9_story.html)

> Enter Jack Tobin, a former Miami defense lawyer who made so much money “defending insurance companies in personal injury actions” that he retired early  ... As the title of James Sheehan’s engaging thriller makes clear, Jack is a **“lawyer’s lawyer,”** and the case against the convict, Thomas Felton, cries out for a second look.

[Imran Amed in *The Business of Fashion*:](http://www.businessoffashion.com/2013/12/remembering-peter-kaplan-an-editors-editor.html)

> As I later learned, Peter was a real **editor’s editor**, having mentored and trained writers who would become key staffers at some of New York’s most important and respected media organisations, from *The New Yorker* to *The New York Times*.

[Gregory P. Kane in *The Baltimore Sun*:](http://articles.baltimoresun.com/1994-12-18/news/1994352088_1_johnson-annapolis-new-chief)

> Detective Brenda Leigh Higgs, a 15-year veteran, called Chief Johnson **"a policeman's policeman"** who "hasn't forgotten what it's like to be a policeman on the street."

Comment: Not for that construction in particular but it's an example of [snowcloning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowclone)

Comment: A beneficent redundancy?

Comment: A peer-based plaudit? I've not come across a term in general use.

Answer (score 9):

According to "[Construction Grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_grammar)" (schema-based grammar), they are a type of **constructional idiom** [X's X]. Their concreteness level is almost abstract because they are not that lexically specified.

---

From the book "Functionalism and Formalism in Linguistics: General papers"
 *edited by Mike Darnell*:

[image]

---

Another explanation from the book "The Reality of Linguistic Rules"
 *By Susan D. Lima, Roberta Corrigan, Gregory K. Iverson*:

[image]

---

They can also be a representation of **formal (schematic) idiom**.

From the article "Language and Cognition II Construction Grammar" *by Prof. Holger Diessel*:

[image]

---

They fall under "genitive compounds" (descriptive genitives) also. So it can be called an "**idiomatic genitive compound**" as well.

Here is another passage along with the description of "constructional idiom": (from the book "The Grammar of Words: An Introduction to Linguistic Morphology *By Geert Booij*"

[image]

Comment: +1 Great answer. I suspect, however, that 'constructional idiom' is not a unique descriptor of (X's X) but of a broader scope.

Comment: @Kris: Thanks. I mentioned as a type of it. I don't think there is a unique descriptor for this idiomatic form.

Comment: Yes, wonderful stuff. I'd have given you the usual sticker if you'd asked the question "What is a 'constructional idiom'?" and answered it yourself.

Comment: Excellent answer! I like the section from "Functionalism and Formalism" in particular, as it situates the idiom within a formal-concrete continuum. It's also written clearly. Is the rest of the book (and the others you cite) navigable by a (patient) lay person?

Comment: 'Fixed Expressions and Idioms in English', by Rosamund Moon, is the most thorough monograph I've come across (though ermanem's sources look very good). It's lengthy, but readable. But I can't find a term specifically describing the construction _an X's X_.

Comment: @A Brooks: You are welcome! I did not read the entire book but the first source seems more readable. You can try reading the section related to this topic first.

Answer (score 2):

I'd call that type of construction **possessive reduplication**. The examples on Wikipedia may not match exactly the one the OP is asking for, but its meaning is clear and sometimes words have to be bent a little, to fit *our* needs.

> [Reduplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplication#English) in linguistics is a morphological process in which the root or stem of a word (or part of it) or **even the whole word is repeated exactly or with a slight change.**
>   Reduplication is used in inflections to convey a grammatical function, such as plurality, intensification, etc., and in lexical derivation to create new words. It is often used when a speaker adopts a tone more "expressive" or figurative than ordinary speech and is also often, but not exclusively, **iconic in meaning**.

---

EDIT
The accepted meaning of "[a man's man](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/a-man-s-man)" *is a man who enjoys men's activities and being with other men*, i.e. the expression emphasizes the qualities of being a man. Likewise a *lawyer's lawyers* will imply that the person being compared personifies the typical or ideal lawyer. So perhaps the term **emphatic reduplication** or as suggested by @medica, **intensifying reduplication**, would be a more appropriate and accurate term.

Comment: I thought so too. Maybe an intensifying reduplication? I couldn't support it, however.

Comment: @medica that's probably a more accurate term! I'll have to do a little research on the idiom.

Comment: Well,  I'm not saying I fully disagree, but an explanation for the downvote would be appreciated.

Comment: I admit I'm torn between accepting this answer, as it is more precise, or ermanen's as it gives more context.

Comment: @ABrooks before awarding any answer, wait a bit. Someone might come up with a more convincing term.

Comment: Sensible advice.

Comment: This article on [contrastive reduplication](http://ase.tufts.edu/philosophy/documents/Jackendoff/salad-salad.pdf) contains: Thus the ‘scope’ of CR cannot be deﬁned in purely phonological terms; rather, a
combination of phonological, morphosyntactic, syntactic, and lexical factors is involved. Hmm. I'd say '_coffee_ coffee' is used to distinguish it from the undrinkable stuff. Similarly, a 'lawyer's lawyer' is (as opposed to the free one you get if you can't afford ...). So the pragmatics involved are similar. The genetive 's, as you say, is a formal point of difference.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It kinda fits. Reduplication is, I believe, (no discredit to ermanen's fine research) more *accessible* for the average person.

Comment: Thank you @EdwinAshworth for the link! I've only just read the paper, CR exists in Italian too e.g. *occhi neri neri* (really dark brown eyes (or) not just dark brown but brown brown eyes) *Wierzbicka proposes instead that the communicative import of
syntactic reduplication is to insist on the **validity** of what is said. She writes
that “[i]n calling someone’s eyes neri neri the speaker insists that these
eyes were ‘really’ black, literally black”* Could it be the X's X idiom arose from "He's a man man." And subsequently the -'s was added, for reasons of euphony?

Comment: *Basically, CR can copy less than a word by leaving out
inﬂectional sufﬁxes and copying only the stem. Technically, the copy is
still a word, but it is smaller than the word that it ‘copies from’. (...) GUY–guys, y’know? Those guys with skills? Not KID–kids, men-kids. ©* Interesting stuff, albeit 46 pages PAGES is a bit too many :)

Comment: You may be right. Sounds like research research is needed, though. And the X's X idiom could be modelled on the well-known (if only because of the popularity of 'Jeeves and Wooster') gentleman's gentleman. Though this is not the same sort of idiom (if it is an idiom at all) beneath the surface, of course, using two different senses of 'gentleman'. The one we're looking at is a rewrite for 'proper X' in a less naive register (Sherlock and his patronising 'Oh, you're a proper genius too!?').